# Popup not showed (android)

Tags: android, layout, popup

I use a example code of stackoverflow for showing a PopUp at the OnCreate method. My app doesn't break, but it doesn't show the popup. I put the code below:

```
private void showExplain() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupexplicativo, null);

    final PopupWindow windows = new PopupWindow(layout , 300,300,true);
    windows.setFocusable(false);
    windows.setTouchable(true);
    windows.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    layout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            windows.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

On the onCreate method I call showExplain();

Can anyone helps me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

popupexplicativo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#444444"
    android:padding="10px"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Transfering data"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/server_status_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Awaiting answer..."
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

        <Button android:id="@+id/end_data_send_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:drawablePadding="3sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your java class,

```
private void initiatePopupWindow(View v) {
            try {
                //We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater, use the context of this activity
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ProfileView.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupexplicativo,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
                // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
                pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
                // display the popup in the center
                pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                TextView mResultText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.server_status_text);
                Button cancelButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.end_data_send_button);
                cancelButton.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is "popupelement"? the popup layout?

Comment: Your linearlayout id

Comment: and what View I have to pass to this method?

Comment: You are inflating custom layout na?

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: my popup is the "popupexplicativo" element, thats the layout, what do you mean when you say your linearlayout id at id.popup_element?

Comment: You are using "popupexplicativo.xml" file na that view you need to pass and the parent layout id u should pass that i have mentioned as "popup_element"

Comment: Look at that xml file and check.you will understand what i have tried to explain you

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it :

below methods are placed in a class Utils (you can have your own Class name, its just a utility class as I have different layout that can be inflated in Pop up window)

```
public static PopupWindow getPopupWindow(Context context, View parentLayout) {
    final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(context);
    popUp.setContentView(parentLayout);
    popUp.setWidth(getScreenWidth(context));
    popUp.setHeight(getScreenHeight(context));
    popUp.setFocusable(true);
    popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
    return popUp;
}


public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return metrics.widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight(Context context) {
    //int statusBarHeight = isFullScreen() ? 0 : getStatusBarHeight();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return metrics.heightPixels - getStatusBarHeight(context);
}


public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And used it like this in your activity

```
final PopupWindow popUp;
popUp= getPopupWindow(mActivity, yourView);
popUp.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
popUp.update(x, y, Utils.getScreenWidth(mActivity), Utils.getScreenHeight(mActivity));
```

Comment: what is anchorView?

Comment: I also have a problem with transparent color

Comment: Utils is the Class and all the method mentionaed above are placed int that

Comment: In case if you want to show the pop up window below a textView or button , that view is anchor view.